setInterval stops executing function in specified interval on LWC in a few minutes
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
// some more imports
import isQwerty from '@salesforce/apex/TimerPage_Ctrl.isQwerty';
import getQwertyData from '@salesforce/apex/TimerPage_Ctrl.getQwertyData';

export default class TimerPage extends LightningElement {

    connectedCallback() {
        isQwerty()
            .then((isQwertyResult) => {
                console.debug('\n --- connectedCallback - isQwerty - isQwertyResult: ', isQwertyResult);
                if (isQwertyResult === true) {
                    getQwertyData()
                        .then((result) => {
                                this.refreshIntervalId = setInterval(this.refreshRemainingTime.bind(this), 1000);
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.error('\n --- connectedCallback - isQwerty - getQwertyData - error: ', error);
                        });

                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
            });
    }

    refreshRemainingTime() {
        console.debug('\n--- refreshRemainingTime - 1 - this.remainingTimeNumber: ', this.remainingTimeNumber);
        const currentdate = new Date(); 
        const datetime = "" + currentdate.getFullYear() + "-"
                + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "-" 
                + currentdate.getDate() + " T "  
                + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                + currentdate.getSeconds();
        console.debug('--- refreshRemainingTime - 2 - datetime: ', datetime);

        if (this.remainingTimeNumber > 0) {
            this.remainingTimeNumber = this.remainingTimeNumber - 1;
            this.remainingTimeText = this.remainingTimeNumber;
        } else {
            clearInterval(this.refreshIntervalId);
            this.finishRunningPomidor();
        }
    }

}

The console in Chrome looks like
--- refreshRemainingTime - 1 - this.remainingTimeNumber:  1200
timerPage.js:1 --- refreshRemainingTime - 2 - datetime:  2024-9-3 T 22:34:58
--- refreshRemainingTime - 1 - this.remainingTimeNumber:  1199
timerPage.js:1 --- refreshRemainingTime - 2 - datetime:  2024-9-3 T 22:34:59
--- refreshRemainingTime - 1 - this.remainingTimeNumber:  1198
timerPage.js:1 --- refreshRemainingTime - 2 - datetime:  2024-9-3 T 22:35:0
--- refreshRemainingTime - 1 - this.remainingTimeNumber:  1197
timerPage.js:1 --- refreshRemainingTime - 2 - datetime:  2024-9-3 T 22:35:1

till
--- refreshRemainingTime - 1 - this.remainingTimeNumber:  1089
timerPage.js:1 --- refreshRemainingTime - 2 - datetime:  2024-9-3 T 22:36:49
--- refreshRemainingTime - 1 - this.remainingTimeNumber:  1088
timerPage.js:1 --- refreshRemainingTime - 2 - datetime:  2024-9-3 T 22:36:50
--- refreshRemainingTime - 1 - this.remainingTimeNumber:  1087
timerPage.js:1 --- refreshRemainingTime - 2 - datetime:  2024-9-3 T 22:37:30
--- refreshRemainingTime - 1 - this.remainingTimeNumber:  1086
timerPage.js:1 --- refreshRemainingTime - 2 - datetime:  2024-9-3 T 22:38:30
--- refreshRemainingTime - 1 - this.remainingTimeNumber:  1085
timerPage.js:1 --- refreshRemainingTime - 2 - datetime:  2024-9-3 T 22:39:30

The question - how to force LWC or Chrome to run the function each second even when I don't look at it?
I saw similar questions (Arrow function not working for setInterval, LWC Set Interval function not working when used inside a wire function). I didn't find answer to my question. Or I didn't understand how to apply those answers to my particular situation.

Modern browsers, including Chrome, can throttle JavaScript timers to save resources when a tab is not in focus.
Instead of using setInterval, you can use requestAnimationFrame to schedule your updates.
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import isQwerty from '@salesforce/apex/TimerPage_Ctrl.isQwerty';
import getQwertyData from '@salesforce/apex/TimerPage_Ctrl.getQwertyData';

export default class TimerPage extends LightningElement {
        refreshIntervalId;
        remainingTimeNumber = 1200; 

        connectedCallback() {
                isQwerty().then((isQwertyResult) => {
                        console.debug('\n --- connectedCallback - isQwerty - isQwertyResult: ', isQwertyResult);
                        if (isQwertyResult === true) {
                                getQwertyData().then((result) => {
                                        this.startTimer();
                                }).catch((error) => {
                                        console.error('\n --- connectedCallback - isQwerty - getQwertyData - error: ', error);
                                });
                        }
                }).catch((error) => {
                        console.error('\n --- connectedCallback - isQwerty - error: ', error);
                });
        }

        startTimer() {
                const update = () => {
                        this.refreshRemainingTime();
                        this.refreshIntervalId = requestAnimationFrame(update);
                };
                this.refreshIntervalId = requestAnimationFrame(update);
        }

        refreshRemainingTime() {
                console.debug('\n--- refreshRemainingTime - 1 - this.remainingTimeNumber: ', this.remainingTimeNumber);
                const currentdate = new Date(); 
                const datetime = `${currentdate.getFullYear()}-${currentdate.getMonth() + 1}-${currentdate.getDate()} T ${currentdate.getHours()}:${currentdate.getMinutes()}:${currentdate.getSeconds()}`;
                console.debug('--- refreshRemainingTime - 2 - datetime: ', datetime);

                if (this.remainingTimeNumber > 0) {
                        this.remainingTimeNumber -= 1;
                        this.remainingTimeText = this.remainingTimeNumber;
                } else {
                        cancelAnimationFrame(this.refreshIntervalId);
                        this.finishRunningPomidor();
                }
        }

        disconnectedCallback() {
                cancelAnimationFrame(this.refreshIntervalId);
        }
}

The requestAnimationFrame is used to repeatedly call the refreshRemainingTime method and the disconnectedCallback lifecycle hook is used to cancel the animation frame when the component is removed from the DOM.

It is said - "requestAnimationFrame() calls are paused in most browsers when running in background tabs or hidden s, in order to improve performance and battery life.". As I understand there is a huge chance to end up with the same problem - my function won't be executed.
